# Apply one hot encoding on a dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, one-hot-encoding

I'm working on a dataset in which I have various string column with different values and want to apply the `one hot encoding`.

Here's the sample dataset:

```
v_4        v5             s_5     vt_5     ex_5          pfv           pfv_cat
0-50      StoreSale     Clothes   8-Apr   above 100   FatimaStore       Shoes
0-50      StoreSale     Clothes   8-Apr   0-50        DiscountWorld     Clothes
51-100    CleanShop     Clothes   4-Dec   51-100      BetterUncle       Shoes
```

So, here I need to apply one-hot encoding on `pvf_cat` like that I have avrious other columns, which I have created a list of these cols as `str_cols`
and here's how I'm applying the `one-hot-encoding`:

```
for col in str_cols:
    data = df[str(col)]
    values = list(data)
    # print(values)
    # integer encode
    label_encoder = LabelEncoder()
    integer_encoded = label_encoder.fit_transform(values)
    print(integer_encoded)
    # one hot encode
    encoded = to_categorical(integer_encoded)
    print(encoded)
    # invert encoding
    inverted = argmax(encoded[0])
    print(inverted)
    onehot_encoder = OneHotEncoder(sparse=False)
    integer_encoded = integer_encoded.reshape(len(integer_encoded), 1)
    onehot_encoded = onehot_encoder.fit_transform(integer_encoded)
```

But it's not affecting the dataset, when I print the `df.head()` it's still the same, what's wrong here?

Comment: You don’t seem to assign anything back to df.

Comment: That's what I'm confused about, how can I do that?

Comment: BTW: I think pd.get_dummies() would be easier for OneHotEncoding then writing your own code.

Comment: Can you write it for my `df `as an answer? If it works I will accept your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `pd.get_dummies()` is way easier then writing your own code for this, and probably also faster.

```
df = pd.get_dummies(df, columns=['pfv_cat'])

      v_4         v5      s_5   vt_5       ex_5            pfv  pfv_cat_Clothes pfv_cat_Shoes
0    0-50  StoreSale  Clothes  8-apr  above 100    FatimaStore                0             1
1    0-50  StoreSale  Clothes  8-apr       0-50  DiscountWorld                1             0
2  51-100  CleanShop  Clothes  4-dec     51-100    BetterUncle                0             1
```

In the list after the `columns=` argument you can specify which columns you want OneHotEncoded. So in your case, this would probably be `df = pd.get_dummies(df, columns=str_cols)`.